# How to show that $f(x) = \sqrt{2lx - l^2}$ is a contraction

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, lipschitz-functions

Let's say I want to find a fun way to write a number $l$. I can procede by doing so:
(as I saw here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400535/can-we-get-just-3-from-pi/400538)

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{2lx - l^2}$. The only fixed point is $f(x) = x \Rightarrow (x-l)^2 = 0 \Rightarrow x = l$.

Now, if we show that $f(x)$ is a contraction over $\mathbb{R}$, (with the usual euclidean distance), then (using the [Banach-Caccioppoli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem)) we can start with any value (say $\pi$) and write

$$...\sqrt{2l\sqrt{2l\sqrt{2l\sqrt{2l\pi - l^2} - l^2}-l^2}-l^2}...  = l$$

But I'm having trouble showing that $f(x)$ is a contraction.

Also,are there some nice generalization and/or related concepts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't. Take $l=1$ as an example.

$$f(x)=\sqrt{2x - 1}$$

Then $|f(1)-f(\frac{1}{2})|=1>|1-\frac{1}{2}|$.

This doesn't rule out that it may be a contraction on certain parts of its domain, of course.

Indeed, let

$$f(x)=\sqrt{2lx-l^2}$$

First of all, look at the graph of $f$ (just use some example value for $l$). You can see that after a while, $f$ is no longer very steep. It would make sense for a function with low slope to be contracting. Specifically, if $f'<1$ between $x$ and $y$, then $f(y)-f(x)=\int^y_xf'(t)dt\leq\int^y_x1dt=y-x$, so $f$ is indeed contracting between $x$ and $y$. So the question is: when does $f'(x)<1$?

This is a simple calculus exercice so I won't bore you, but the answer turns out to be that $f'(x)\leq1$ when $x\geq l$ (assuming $l>0$), and furthermore $f$ maps $[l, +\infty[$ into itself. So $f$ is a contraction on $[l, +\infty[$ and you're fine as long as you pick a starting point greater than $l$.

Comment: I see. If you follow the link, it is taken $l=3$ and the iteration starts at $\pi$. If this is not a contraction, the result is wrong? And if $f(x)$ is a contraction only on certain parts of its domain, can we still apply the Banach theorem?

Comment: @Ant Sure, as long as you can show that $f(D)\subseteq D$, where $D$ is the domain of contraction. And as long as both the desired fixed point and the starting element are both in $D$, of course.

Comment: Oh, right, of course. So can you explain why the answer in the link works? :-)

Comment: @Ant $f$ maps $D=[3, +\infty[$ into itself, and presumably is also a contraction on that domain. And of course $\pi\in D$.

Comment: @Ant I edited my answer to be more complete.

Comment: Thank you very much. Nice and clear!

Answer (score 1):

A thought: For any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, we can find $c \in (x,y) $ such that

$$ |f(x) - f(y) \leq |f'(c)||x-y| $$

by the mean value theorem,

Now, $$f'(c) = \frac{l}{\sqrt{2cl-l^2} }$$

Show $|f'(c)| < 1$

This works if $c > l $

Comment: The problem is near $l$, $f'(c)$ is unbounded

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've accepted the other one though because I think it's a little bit clearer :-)